# Can i create List<class> by class name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to do a function such that when the user selects the class name and clicks the button, it create a new `List<SelectedClass>`. Currently I am using a switch statement like so:

```
switch(Name)
case"a" : List<a> X=new List<a>();
case"b" : List<b> X=new List<b>();
```

Is there another method to do this?

Comment: Does your code not do what you want? What problems did you run into?

Comment: I want search table in database,it can choose table to search.I create a viewmodel cantain each table viewmodel,when search need to create list<table viewmodel>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) (so you won't need any switch statement):

```
Type type = Type.GetType(Name); // Example: Type.GetType("NamespaceName.ClassName")
Type listType = typeof(List<>);
var listWithType = listType.MakeGenericType(new [] { type });
var instanceOfList = Activator.CreateInstance(listWithType);
```

Comment: i try it ,but can't get type.

Comment: I find reason, need  to add the assembly name Type.GetType("NamespaceName.ClassName,NamespaceName")